# How to put PHP into path

Tags: php, console, path

I have just built PHP from source. Usually when I do this, I don't have any problems just running php from anywhere. This time however, the console returns 'command not found'. What do I need to correct for this to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected by your subject, the `PATH` variable needs to be properly updated.

If you are using `bash` as your shell, this can be done in your personal `~/.bashrc` file, or in the global `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` files for all users.  You would add a line like this in either case:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/php/directory/
```